# Prolog - exaclty one element in list without using size or length functions

Tags: prolog

The question states to return `true` if a list has exactly one element without using size of length functions. Therefore, the tail must be empty, how can I go around this?

```
Examples:
?- [1, 2, 3, 8]  
 false
?- [8]
 true
```

Comment: You write a predicate.

Comment: How would you write the predicate?

Comment: `singular([_]).` But try and learn a little Prolog, you'll enjoy it.

Comment: I did almost the same thing but instead of _ I put an H. `oneElement([H]).` Can you explain me the difference?

Comment: `oneElement([H]).` will work as well, it will only *warn* about a singleton variable.

Comment: Singleton variable warnings almost always indicate errors; in this case it would be harmless, but I would strongly encourage you not to get in the habit of ignoring them.

Answer (score 0):

This function will check if the list has a tail without using any built-in functions.

```
oe([_|T],R):-
T =[],
R = true.
```

[execution of function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xkrus.png)